# Como agregar los indices de un array a otro array con una función en JS

Tags: javascript, array, funciones, push

Necesito poder agregar los indices de este arreglo:

let cartoons = ["toy story", "finding Nemo", "kung-fu panda"]

A este arreglo:
let films = ["star wars", "totoro",  "rocky", "pulp fiction",  "la vida es bella"]

Utilizando una función (){
}

No sé por donde empezar ni como hacerlo, ayudaaa! estoy iniciando :(

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar la funcion concat:

```
let cartoons = ["toy story", "finding Nemo", "kung-fu panda", "wally", "fortnite"];
let films = ["star wars", "totoro", "rocky", "pulp fiction", "la vida es bella"];
let newArray = cartoons.concat(films); // ["toy story", "finding Nemo", "kung-fu panda", "wally", "fortnite", "star wars", "totoro", "rocky", "pulp fiction", "la vida es bella"]
```

[Más métodos para manejar arrays](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_array_methods.asp)

Saludos.

Comment: Gracias Gerardo! la solución es correcta, sin embargo, en la consigna me piden no crear un nuevo array y utilizar el metodo .push() :/

Comment: entonces la función seria: cartoons.forEach(function(item){films.push(item)})

Comment: Ok, de nuevo gracias ya lo pongo en práctica!